# append button value in text box

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am appending my button value into text box, but on every click on button my text value is not resetting.

below is my code:

```
$('#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4, #btn5').click(
function(){
    $('#input1').val($('#input1').val()+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

I getting this result if I am click on buttons, how I can reset my text box on every click of button.

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML too?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the input value on each click you have to change:
 `$('#input1').val($('#input1').val()+$(this).val());` 
to
`$('#input1').val($(this).val());` 
Because you actually concatenate current value with next clicked value.
 
I dont know how is exactly your html but I also recommend you add `value` attribute to the buttons with the value you need in the case you havent yet.
Check this example:

```js
$('#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4, #btn5').click(function(){
    $('#input1').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" value="10">10 $</button>
<button id="btn2" value="20">20 $</button>
<button id="btn3" value="30">30 $</button>
<button id="btn4" value="50">50 $</button>
<button id="btn5" value="100">100 $</button><br><br><br>

Value donation: <input type="number" id="input1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() function of javascript to convert string to Integer

Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to know more about parseInt() function of javascript.

Try below code:

```
$('#input1').val(parseInt($(this).val()));
```

If you want to add with previous selected value, use below code:

```
$('#input1').val(parseInt($(this).val())+parseInt($('#input1').val()));
```

Comment: Hi try this code to overwrite with new input

$('#input1').val(parseInt($(this).val()));

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns string. You can't make a sum of string and integer, you need to use `parseInt` function.

```
$('#input1').val(parseInt($('#input1').val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
```

Small example of parseInt:

```
'1' + 2           // 12
parseInt('1') + 2 // 3
```

---

EDIT:

```
$('#input1').val($(this).val());
```

Comment: I know... where is problem? You're looking for `parseInt` as I meant in my post.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: @user2147423: oh, I misunderstood... I've edited my answer.